# How to reset luci password from ssh

Tags: openwrt

I have forgotten my luci password, but can get in via ssh. How do I reset the luci password from the console? I see that in /etc/config/luci there is this:

```
config extern 'flash_keep'
...
        option passwd '/etc/passwd'
...
```

So is it done with the regular passwd command?

Comment: That's what it looks like. Maybe it uses a non-root user for luci authentication.

Comment: The user I've normally logged in as to luci is root, though I want to change that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can change root password use  `passwd`  command via ssh.  Normally,the root password is luci password.

```
\# passwd

Changing password for root

New password:
```

Answer (score 2):

You actually have to issue `mount_root` before using `passwd`, then reboot. The method in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25121036/139040) alone didn't work for me (18.06.1)

```
root@(none):~# mount_root
switching to jffs2 overlay
root@(none):/rom/root# passwd
Changing password for root
New password:
Retype password:
passwd: password for root changed by root
root@(none):/rom/root# reboot -f
```

via https://openwrt.org/docs/guide-user/troubleshooting/root_password_reset

Answer (score 1):

If you'd like to use a non-root user for luci, I did this on a project a few months ago:

https://github.com/sudomesh/luci-app-peopleswifi/blob/master/luasrc/controller/peopleswifi/index.lua

where "admin" was another user in openwrt. It should be said that my understanding is that openwrt is specifically not secure in multi-user environments. While theoretically you can not give that "admin" user a login shell, I'm not sure that I would depend on this solution as a secure alternative to using luci authentication as root.